# Transform list to map with first two letters as index

Tags: elixir

I have the list:

```elixir
["AM00", "CC11", "CB11"]
```

I need to transform this list in map like this:

```elixir
%{"AM" => "00", "CC" => "11", "CB" => "11"}
```

I tried with Enum.map but it didn't work:

```elixir
["AM00", "CC11", "CB11"]
|> Map.new(&Enum.map(&1, fn x -> x end), %{})
```

Comment: Please note that this transform is unsafe (if there are two elements with the same letters, the former will be overwritten.) One should collect a map `letters => list_of_digits` in such a case to be safe. (E. g. `%{"AA" => ["00"], ...}`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary pattern matching can dissect the string:

```
   data = ["AM00", "CC11", "CB11"]

   for <<key::binary-size(2), value::binary>> <- data, into: %{} do
     {key, value}
   end
```

output:

```
%{"AM" => "00", "CB" => "11", "CC" => "11"}
```

That only works for single byte characters.

To handle `UTF-8` characters as well as `ASCII` characters:

```
   data = ["èü00", "C€11", "€ä11"]

   for <<char1::utf8, char2::utf8, rest::binary>> <- data, into: %{} do
    {<<char1::utf8, char2::utf8>>, rest}
   end
```

output:

```
%{"C€" => "11", "èü" => "00", "€ä" => "11"}
```

Comment: @FlavioMilan, Do you want the values to be strings or integers?  I edited my answer to provide integers...but notice `0` instead of `00`.

Comment: As string... the first example worked, i'll adjust only the names

Comment: @FlavioMilan,  Okay.  Change your desired output in your question, and I'll rollback my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/2) and [`String.split_at/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split_at/2):

```elixir
Map.new(["AM00", "CC11", "CB11"], &String.split_at(&1, 2))
```

Comment: Simple and efficient.

Comment: Very nice shortcut! It handles UTF-8 characters as well as ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to transform this list [into a] map...I tried with `Enum.map`.

You can also use [Enum.reduce](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) instead of `Enum.map` when you want the result to be a map. The following example uses `Enum.reduce` and it can handle single byte `ASCII` characters as well as `UTF-8` (multi-byte) characters:

```
   ["AM00", "CC11", "CB11"]

                initial value for acc variable
                   |
                   V
   |> Enum.reduce(%{},
        fn str, acc -> 
          {first_two, last_two} = String.split_at(str, 2)
          Map.put(acc, first_two, last_two)  # return the new value for acc
        end
      )
```

output:

```
%{"AM" => "00", "CB" => "11", "CC" => "11"}
```

And:

```
    ["èü00", "C€11", "€ä11"]

    |> Enum.reduce(%{},
        fn str, acc -> 
          {first_two, last_two} = String.split_at(str, 2)
          Map.put(acc, first_two, last_two)
        end
       )
```

output:

```
%{"C€" => "11", "èü" => "00", "€ä" => "11"}
```

Comment: Excellent example!